# Having issue with my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Please enter to my website http://www.smiths-heimann.az with Chrome.

Minimize browser window for a minute then Maximize.

Can you see the difference? Animation goes incredibly fast.. What is that? How can i fix it. Thx in advance,

Comment: it looks fine to me. which chrome version do you using?

Comment: thx for fast reply. seems it was bug of jquery 1.6.2. the plugins i'm using are not compatible with the latest jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem, I think: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381
try switching to jQuery 1.5.2